# undefined method `people_index_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, form-for

I'm learning rails and have encountered a problem I can not find a solution to.

When I am using a form for editing and creating new persons, I get this error

```
undefined method 'people_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f68442da790>:0x007f6850013410>
```

On the following line.

```
<%= form_for @people do |f| %>
```

This is what my rake routes look like.

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
       root GET    /                          welcome#index
     events GET    /events(.:format)          events#index
            POST   /events(.:format)          events#create
  new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)      events#new
 edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format) events#edit
      event GET    /events/:id(.:format)      events#show
            PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
            PUT    /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
            DELETE /events/:id(.:format)      events#destroy
     people GET    /people(.:format)          people#index
            POST   /people(.:format)          people#create
 new_person GET    /people/new(.:format)      people#new
edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format) people#edit
     person GET    /people/:id(.:format)      people#show
            PATCH  /people/:id(.:format)      people#update
            PUT    /people/:id(.:format)      people#update
            DELETE /people/:id(.:format)      people#destroy
```

And the controller

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @people = People.new
    end

    def edit
        @people = People.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @people = People.find(params[:id])
        if @people.update(people_params)
            redirect_to people_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def show
        @people = People.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @all_people = People.all
    end

    def create
        @people = People.new(people_params)

        if @people.save
            redirect_to @people
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
       @people = People.find(params[:id])
       @people.destroy

       redirect_to people_path
    end

    private
        def people_params
            params.require(:people).permit(:name, :pno, :gender)
        end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140417200735) do

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "location"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "people", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "pno"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

routes.rb

```
Nightlife::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :events, :people
end
```

Full error message. I do only get errors while creating a new person.

```
NoMethodError in People#new
Showing /home/oalsing/Documents/Websites/Rails/Nightlife/app/views/people/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `people_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f68442da790>:0x007f68481c42a8>
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
2
3
4

  <%= form_for @people do |f| %>

      <% if @people.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/people/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/oalsing/Documents/Websites/Rails/Nightlife

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/people/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_people__form_html_erb__3105468428477628872_70042931049120'
app/views/people/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_people_new_html_erb__2301167718720189466_70042999118360'
Request

Parameters:

None
```

Comment: In which of your files you are having that code snippet?

Comment: can you show your routes.rb

Comment: If you are trying to create a new record then give it as `<%= form_for @people, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>`

Comment: aelor, I've inserted routes.rb in my original post.

Pavan, I'll give it a try! I thought it would be possible to use the _form.html.erb that I've used for events, not having to use url:.

Comment: For which action its throwing error, new or edit?, post your error log

Comment: RSB, using the form_for that I've posted it only encounters errors while creating a new person. Editing an existing person works.

Comment: Pavan, using the url: {action: "create"} it works. Though this solution is not really what I'm looking for, because then I also have to create a form for updating existing persons.

Comment: @oalsing For now that's the answer to your question

Comment: @Pavan Thank you. 

I've updated the original post with the full error message.

Comment: Try the answer I've posted once, tell me if it works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why everybody here don't point out the problem in model name.

If you have a `PeopleController`, the model should be `Person` but NOT `People` because "people" is plural of "person".

And the instance name should be `@person` but not `@people`.

Rails convention is not a must. But please respect it when you can. Only break it when you really have to and know every in and out.

The named path has already bite you. You'll see more for breaking the convention.

Comment: Yes that's what I said him, convention over configuration failed here due to his naming

Comment: Thank you. I've used the correct conventions and everything works well with the _form that I did intend to use from the very beginning. I will be more careful with conventions in the future.

Comment: @oalsing, nice you found the convenience of the conventions :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this when the form is same

```
<%= form_for @people, :url => (@people.new_record? ? (people_path) : (person_path(@people))), :method => (@people.new_record? ? "post" : "put") do |f| %>
```

Comment: I've tried that! It solves the problem when creating a new person. But when I do update an already existing person, I get this error.

Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/people"

Comment: then I'm editing the answer which would work with both

Comment: This works very well, thank you. I am surprised that this problem would need such an advanced url.

Comment: @oalsing its just that you need to provide urls for both. you can better use different forms for your create and update action.

Comment: It's because here rails' convention over configuration failed due to naming convention

Comment: @aelor Yes, I will create two different forms rather then using the partial.

Comment: If you use different forms, then for creating new record use `people_path` and while editing use `person_path` with object passed as parameter

Comment: @oalsing Its the best way using `form_tag` instead of `form_for` so that you will be having one `_form.html.erb` only for both actions.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments,you are trying to create a new `People` record,so change your code to like this

```
<%= form_for @people, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

thats a long standing bug , Check rails [issues page](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769)

This works in case of edit but wont work on create.

This is what the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) have to say:

> A long-standing bug prevents form_for from working automatically with
>   singular resources. As a workaround, specify the URL for the form
>   directly, like so:

```
form_for @geocoder, url: geocoder_path do |f|
```

so in your case ,

```
<%= form_for @people, url: people_path do |f| %>
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using your solution I am able to create new Persons, but when editing an existing person I get the following error 

Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/people"